# Best filesystem for a shared data space?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, fat32

I want to have a partition mounted to both Window's "My Documents" and Ubuntu's "My Documents".  What are the advantages and disadvantages of FAT and NTFS?  Is there an accepted standard or common way of doing this?

By FAT, I mean either FAT, FAT16, FAT32, or exFAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found in my experience that reading NTFS from linux is never a problem, but writing to NTFS from linux has corrupted several drives in practice. FAT32 is usually the easiest (nearly all OSes support it without any extra drivers/software), but if you need large file support, exFAT is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comparsion between those two [here](http://www.theeldergeek.com/ntfs_or_fat32_file_system.htm)

I would personally use NTFS over FAT because of better error recovery. FAT is old technology.

Comment: The problem is that most comparisons (that one included) are for purposes of a whole-disk Windows install.  I'm looking for more of a description of pros and cons and which should be used *between OSes*.  How is the error recovery better on NTFS?  Is NTFS journalled?